# Content-Security-Policy differences between Chrome/Firefox and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, security, safari, content-security-policy, brightcove

In `connect-src` we specify `https://secure.brightcove.com` and in `media-src` we specify only `'self'`.

This will play the brightcove videos without issues in chrome and firefox. But in safari we will get the following error:

`Refused to load https://secure.brightcove.com because it does not appear in the media-src directive`.

If we add the url to the media-src directive then it will work on safari too, but why would there be differences?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  If so, could you post as an answer?